# This subscription isrestricted from provisioning MySQL server in this regionPlease choose a different region with service,subscription limit issue typ

Tags: mysql, azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am getting below error while provisioning Mysql database in this region and others to, for more information I have Microsoft Azure Sponsorship, still getting error.

Here is the mysql terraform script I am using to provision:

```
> Error: Error creating MySQL Server "mysql-db-server" (Resource Group
> "devopspoc-360f-primary1"): mysql.ServersClient#Create: Failure
> sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error:
> Code="ProvisioningDisabled" Message="This subscription is restricted
> from provisioning MySQL servers in this region. Please choose a
> different region or open a support request with service and
> subscription limits (quotas) issue type."
```

main.tf :

```
resource "azurerm_mysql_server" "mysql" {
  name                = var.mysql_server_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  depends_on          = [var.resource_group_name]
  #sku_name = "B_Gen5_2"
   sku_name = "GP_Gen5_2"

  storage_profile {
    storage_mb            = 5120
    backup_retention_days = 7
    geo_redundant_backup  = "Disabled"
  }

  administrator_login          = "var.mysql_un"
  administrator_login_password = "var.mysql_pw"
  version                      = "8.0"
  ssl_enforcement              = "Enabled"
  tags = {
        environment = "Test"
    }
}

resource "azurerm_mysql_database" "mysql" {
  name                = var.db_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  server_name         = azurerm_mysql_server.mysql.name
  charset             = "utf8"
  collation           = "utf8_unicode_ci"

}
resource "azurerm_mysql_firewall_rule" "mysql" {
  name                = var.mysql_firewall_rule_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  server_name         = azurerm_mysql_server.mysql.name
  start_ip_address    = "xx.x.x.x"
  end_ip_address      = "xx.x.x.x"
}

resource "azurerm_mysql_virtual_network_rule" "mysql" {
  name                = var.mysql_vnet_rule
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  server_name         = azurerm_mysql_server.mysql.name
  subnet_id           = var.backend_vnet_subnet_id
}
```

Again I tried with different sku version too, still getting same.

Comment: What region are you attempting to run that in? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/global-infrastructure/services/?products=mysql&regions=all shows an availability chart.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is likely due to covid19-related restrictions put in place. Unfortunately not something that can be resolved here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably disabled due to compute shortage (sars-cov-2) right now. otherwise try using different regions. but as far as I know most of the free subscriptions are not working right now

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried in different regions on various time, still getting same.

Comment: As my id, didn't had permission in the region where I am trying. It got fixed in the EastUs region.

Comment: you cant issue RBAC roles to regions, so that is not really possible